# Is it possible to run a virtual machine within another virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, desktop-computer

Is it possible to have a virtual machine that is only 1 GB in a virtual machine that is 4 GB on a Windows 10 desktop?

Will decreasing disk and memory space with both virtual machines make your computer have a shorter life span(I don't know if disk space and memory space contribute to a shorter life span or not)?

Comment: “…would it make your computer have a shorter life span?” Why would you think a VM in a VM would shorten your computer’s lifespan?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am new to VM and have learned that VM takes up a lot of disk and memory space while my VM testing desktop only has 100 GB of space which I made by  myself.

Comment: @jjoa - Using disk space does not shorten the lift of a computer.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for increasing my 1 month knowledge of computers.

Comment: @jjoa - You are concerned about the disk usage, if you are that concerned, install a bigger disk.  Your question is not clear, you have not defined, what you mean by "safe" in the question itself.  I am not alone in this confusion. Just because you accepted an answer does not mean it's the best answer that can be submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to run a virtual machine within another virtual
> machine?

Yes, you can run a virtual machine within another virtual machine (your question)

You need a Virtual App that supports nested Virtual Machines.  VMware supports that.

As to will it damage your machine?

No. Not at all.  I have had a Windows 10 desktop running with 3 virtual machines essentially (98%) non-stop since the COVID pandemic began nearly 2 years ago.

No damage whatever.

Your host machine needs enough memory and disk space, but so long as all fits (I keep 25% free disk space at least), it should work and again, no damage.

If your host has an SSD drive, make sure TRIM has been schedule to run at least each month.